# how to download an xml namespace and use on local server?

Tags: php, xml, soap, curl, simplexml

I am trying to transform an xml document using simpleXML, but the server that holds the name space responds slowly so if possible I want to move the file that holds the namespace to my server.

Here is the code that calls it:

```
$XML = simplexml_load_string($result,NULL,NULL,"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
$XML->registerXPathNamespace('tree','www.tree.com');<----want to point it to my server instead
$var = $XML->xpath('//tree:data');
```

Comment: Don't be so impatient! When you ask a question, half the people in the world are asleep in their beds.

Comment: I am receiving an xml document via soap. I only know the node names. When I run the above script it sometimes works. Other times it does not. I assume $XML->registerXPathNamespace('tree','www.tree.com') www.tree.com is incorrect. How would I even know which one to use?

Answer (score 0):

A namespace is not a file or a resource. You should not normally attempt to use a namespace URI to fetch anything from the web. If you do so, it's quite unpredictable whether you will get anything back, and if so, what it might be. It's not clear to me why you are fetching the namespace URI or what XML you expect to find there, but it is clear from your question that you haven't understood namespaces.

Comment: I am recieving an xml document via soap. I only know the node names. When I run the above script it sometimes works. Other times it does not. I assume $XML->registerXPathNamespace('tree','www.tree.com') www.tree.com is incorrect. How would I even know which one to use?